# How to make loops shorter, cleaner, when using many variables?

Tags: python, class, arguments

Is there a nice way to make loop look cleaner? Can I somehow make two loops below to look more clean, shorter? Is there are different way of defining all the parameters =0?

```
current = []
voltage = []
#parameters add shift value with every device loop
m = 0
n = 0
t = 0
u = 0
w = 0 
for device in range(0, rows*columns):
    m += shift_horizontal_per_device
    n += shift_vertical_per_device
    t += shif_param_a_per_device
    u += shif_param_b_per_device
    w += shif_param_c_per_device
    # parameters add shift value with every pad loop
    o = 0 
    l = 0
    p = 0
    r = 0
    s = 0
    for pad in range(0, pads):
        o += shift_horizontal_per_pad
        l += shift_vertical_per_pad
        p += shif_param_a_per_pad
        r += shif_param_b_per_pad
        s += shif_param_c_per_pad
        x = np.linspace(voltage_min,voltage_max,ids_per_pad)
        y = (lambda a,b,c,x: eval(math_fun))(a+p+t,b+r+u,c+s+w,x)
        x += o+m
        y += n+l
        voltage.extend(x)
        current.extend(y)
```

Comment: It'd look far cleaner if you used real variable names instead of letters

Comment: I assign incrementation to the values of the names, it would make the code much longer if I changed the letters with names, so not sure about that, the vinze answear seems to make it much better.
m += shift_horizontal_per_device
n += shift_vertical_per_device
t += shif_param_a_per_device
u += shif_param_b_per_device
w += shif_param_c_per_device        
o += shift_horizontal_per_pad
l+= shift_vertical_per_pad
p += shif_param_a_per_pad
r += shif_param_b_per_pad
s += shif_param_c_per_pad

Comment: The code is already clean, Maybe try using some meaningful names and use comments describing a set of operations, they might be better. Instead of "m, t, u" unless those values are remembered it is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The least convoluted way I see could be:

```
current = []
voltage = []
m, n, t, u, w = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
for device in range(0, rows*columns):
    m += shift_horizontal_per_device
    n += shift_vertical_per_device
    t += shif_param_a_per_device
    u += shif_param_b_per_device
    w += shif_param_c_per_device
    o, l, p, r, s = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    for pad in range(0, pads):
        o += shift_horizontal_per_pad
        l += shift_vertical_per_pad
        p += shif_param_a_per_pad
        r += shif_param_b_per_pad
        s += shif_param_c_per_pad
        x = np.linspace(voltage_min,voltage_max,ids_per_pad)
        y = (lambda a,b,c,x: eval(math_fun))(a+p+t,b+r+u,c+s+w,x)
        x += o+m
        y += n+l
        voltage.extend(x)
        current.extend(y)
```